# How to define <![CDATA[ ]]> attribute in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, cdata

I am working with Swagger to define my api definition. I have a  comments that I need to define using swagger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183/113116) is not part of XML logical structure, it's just a way to indicate text containing special characters - in order to prevent such text from being interpreted as XML markup.

Simply define CDATA's parent element as `type: string`, that's all. There's no need to indicate CDATA markers in any way. It's up to the server and clients to send an XML element's text as CDATA when necessary.

For example

```xml
<root>
  <elem><![CDATA[ ... ]]></elem>
</root>
```

is defined as:

```yaml
swagger: "2.0"
...

definitions:
  root:
    type: object
    properties:
      elem:
        type: string
```